# How to create a fast pseudo-random hashCode?

Tags: java, hashcode, webassembly, jwebassembly

I am working on a Java to WebAssembly compiler ([JWebAssembly](https://github.com/i-net-software/JWebAssembly)). I need to replace native code with things that can run in WebAssembly.

For java.lang.Object.hashCode() and java.lang.System.identityHashCode() I use currently the follow JavaScript code:

```
identityHashCode = (o) => {
  var h = o[1];
  while( h == 0 ){
    o[1] = h = Math.round( ( Math.random() - 0.5 ) * 0xffff );
  }
  return h;
}
```

But this required for every new hashCode a round trip to the JavaScript scope which cost performance. With a browserless environment (without JavaScript) like WASI this will not work. That I search for a poor replacement.

I think a hashCode:

- does not need be really random
- the values must only be well distributed

Is this correct?

The follow Java code should be good enough.

```
private static int globalHash = (int)System.currentTimeMillis();

private int hashCode;
public int hashCode() {
  if( hashCode == 0 ) {
    hashCode = globalHash = (globalHash + 1) * 31; 
  }
  return hashCode;
}
```

Is this good enough for a generic hashCode function? Would there a better implementation?

Comment: Wouldn't that make a single object return different hashcodes on consecutive calls?

Comment: @pafauk. No, it'll be cached, but this still looks odd. @Horcrux7, why not use `Random`?

Comment: @user WebAssembly has no random build in. It required a library from outside or a browser API.

Comment: @Horcrux7 I see. Is the hash code not very likely to be used? Because if you know it's almost certainly going to be called, you can always generate it in the constructor itself and take extra precautions to make it thread-safe.

Comment: @user Does not understand what you means. Because many classes override hashCode() and not every Object is put into a HashMap or equals that I expect that it is needed only for a small set of objects. I see also no threading problem.

Comment: @Horcrux7 I meant that if you're using a static variable, multiple threads could access it

Comment: @user Threading is no problem in WebAssembly. It is mostly single thread. It is not possible to share a variable between threads. But this is not related to the question. The question is if my hashCode function good enough.

Comment: @Horcrux7 It seems to be? You might want to put this on Code Review though, I'm not sure